# Why do my movie genres come back empty in XA.Reference while using Solr?

Tags: sxa

- I setup the XA.Reference site using Sitecore 8.2.7 with SXA 1.7.
- I configured the Solr settings as described by the Sitecore documentation.

After indexing the content, all of the movies come back but the facet data is empty.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

After discussing with Saul in the Sitecore Slack Chat, he pointed out that the field name needs to match what is in Solr. I suspect this is the case because it's not a custom computed index field, which would have its own settings patched to define the field type.

I had to change the field name to get results back from SXA, but then also needed to rename the facet item for it to render properly.

[image]